# Проблема с формой обратной связи

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть элемент с названием шрифта:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio_check" value="GothicRus" name="font">
```

Нужно всего лишь отправить на почту наименование шрифта взяв его с поля.
Вот код, который я написал, параметр font в адресной строке передается, все хорошо, но никак не отправляет на почту

HTML

```
 <input type="radio" class="radio_check" value="GothicRus" name="font">
```

JS

```
$('#tab1_submit').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php/mail.php",
        data: $(this).serialize() 
    }).done(function(){
        alert("Доставлено");
    });
    return false;
});
```

**#tab1_submit - это кнопка формы, в которой находится элемент radio. 
По нажатию этой кнопки происходит ajax запрос.**

PHP

```
<?php
$msg_box = "";

$recepient = "<здесь моя почта>@gmail.com";
$sitename = "Название сайта";

$font = trim($_POST["font"]);

$message = "Имя: $font";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

?>

Сделал проверку в логах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте продампить `$_POST`, и посмотрите что там есть. А именно `print_r($_POST);`, ибо может сама форма из Ajax даже не прилетать.

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` - возможно `this` - это кнопка. Соответственно, полей формы в ней нет.

Answer (score 0):

> параметр font в адресной строке передается

значит у тебя форма сабмитится без аякса и в таком случае это `$_GET` а не `$_POST`. Если делать без аякса в теге `form` укажи корректный `action` и `method`

---

Если все-таки аяксом делаешь:

В твоем случае `$(this)` - это кнопка, а не форма которую тебе надо отправить.
лучше сделай вот так:

```
$('#your_form_id').on('submit', function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php/mail.php",
        data: $(this).serializeArray() 
    }).done(function(){
        alert("Доставлено");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Аякс запрос проходит, выводит alert сообщение, что доставлено, но сообщение не приходит. Может ошибка в php файле?

Comment: 1. Детальнее что ты используешь XAMP, LAMP, OpenServer? 2. Посмотри логи. 3. Сделай в конце php файла `echo $font; exit;` 4. `done(function(){` поменяй на `done(function(response){ console.log(response);` и посмотри что у тебя будет в консоле браузера

Comment: Использую openserver

Comment: @user207012 По умолчанию OpenServer сохраняет письма и темповой папке и не отправляет никуда. <openserver_root>/userdata\temp\email смотри все свои письма здесь, если ты не менял настройки отправки писем